# open report according to report type

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have serveral report type in database i.e.

```
type nrtype
0002 report1
0011 report2
0007 report3
0010 report4
0012 report4
0013 report5
```

now i have data in grid view and there is column nrtype and in that column there is dropdown and this drop down fill these above all nrtypes .. now i am done with when user select 0002 ,0011 ,0007 type or any report which report is created.. report is displayed in another window but now i also want when user select 0012 ,0013 or any other type . the type which report is not created  then i show message report is not available

```
  if (ds != null && ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    string nrType = Convert.ToString(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["NRType"]);
                    if (nrType == "0002")
                        ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report1.rpt";
                    else if (nrType == "0011")
                        ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report2.rpt";
                    else if (nrType == "0007")
                        ReportObj.ReportFileName = "report3.rpt";
                  else if (nrtype .......( same as above)
```

when report is displayed this report call viewer.aspx and then dispalyed

```
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "NR";
              Hashtable ReportParameters = new Hashtable();
              sReportId = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
              Session["RptInfo" + sReportId] = ReportObj;

              string sUrl = "~/Common/Reports/Viewer.aspx?RptId=" + sReportId;
              ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newtab", "window.open('" + ResolveUrl(sUrl) + "');", true);
```

where as i want when report not found then pop up appear .. no report
i try this

```
else if (nrType == "0014")
                    {
                    string display ="Pop-up";
                    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"Not avaible","alert('"+display+"');"+true);
                    }
```

pop not appear .. error occurred and shows invalid report file path

any solution?

Comment: what does this report type do? on which bases you have set such report type. what path it makes! share more details

Comment: these report type are in dropdown .. when i select report type i.e. i select report 1 then all data with report1.rpt data is displayed in grdiview